# Debugging one thread holds up others?

Tags: multithreading

I have a basic question. I am debugging an application and the editor shows 20 threads at one point of time. The control is with one thread which has hit a breakpoint. Will the remaining 19 threads be held up at their respective instructions till the time control is with first one? Or this there a possibility that other threads steal some execution while I debug the first one?

Comment: Could you add a language and enviorament your using

Comment: It does depend on the type of debugger and the debugging environment being used, but the usual answer is yes, the other threads will be suspended.

Comment: Which debugger ? gdb ? devenv ? ...

Comment: @dragon112 @VGE @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I am using devenv VS2008 and gdb, have used Borland Builder earlier. Language is C++. But your comments bring up an interesting point. Can you please elaborate on them? One when a breakpoint is hit and second when I step through the code?

Comment: @David @hexa: Thanks. I learnt something today which I was missing out earlier although I did thank everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking about Visual Studio... when it hits the breakpoint, all threads are suspended.  But when you are stepping through code, even if you intend to debug a single thread, other threads also get an opportunity to run, this is the default behavior.

You can however freeze individual threads in the Threads window, right-click a thread to see the context menu.  Then while you are stepping through the code, "frozen" threads do not get run.

Comment: +1 for the best answer so far, and esp. qualification regarding specific IDE. Eclipse/Java does NOT suspend other threads when one hits a BP.

Comment: Thanks for replying and +1. When other (unfrozen)threads run while you step through the code, does the control return back to the same place allowing you to resume step through? I use Visual Studio2008 and sometimes gdb. Is the behavior in gdb different from Visual Studio? Language is C++.

Comment: Regarding VS2008, yes, when you step through the code, all unfrozen threads get a momentary chance to run, how much time they get, and whether they actually run at all, is determined by the OS scheduler.  "Momentary" since the app runs until the next breakpoint is hit, or until the current line finishes executing, if stepping through a line of code.  I don't anything about gdb unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

All threads are suspended when the debugger breaks in.

Answer (score 1):

The process is usually suspended, so all thread are suspended.